# Lambda and SQS Retry Strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, retrypolicy

Looking for input on optimizing a lambda retry strategy using SQS. Currently I have a Lambda function that is invoked by an S3 PUT operation which posts to a third party web hook and I'm trying to account for possible errors/500s from said webhook. I've set up two SQS queues for use as a retry policy which looks like this:

```
S3 PUT -> Lambda
Lambda throws error -> Retry twice ->
Move to first SQS queue -> Picked up by second Lambda function for re-processing ->
If re-processing lambda fails, put message back on queue ->
After 5 retries -> move to DLQ for manual evaluation
```

However, after re-evaluating that strategy, I realized I have two lambda functions doing exactly the same thing (the lambda that gets trigged by S3 PUT, and the lambda that "re-processes", both are just hitting the webhook). My second thought was something along the lines of:

```
S3 PUT -> SQS Queue ->
Lambda function to process queue message ->
Failed messages go back on queue ->
After X retries move to DLQ
```

This would eliminate the need for an additional lambda doing the exact same thing. Are there any scalability/cost concerns that I'm not accounting for? The only benefit I can think of with having two lambdas is double the concurrency limits, since retries would be handled by separate function.
For reference, the daily throughput of this process should be around 10-15k invocations a day on the high side.

Answer (score 0):

Option two is the way to go although you should keep track of the number of retries you're doing in the message you put to the queue, as SQS won't know how many retries you've already had up to that point, when you put the message back in the queue.

In terms of scaling it doesn't really matter if you have one or two Lambda functions, because Lambda will scale out horizontally anyway. You can choose to limit how many instances of any particular Lambda exists at any time, but by default there is only the soft limit of 1000 concurrent executions in your account.

You should be careful how you're dealing with errors and retries. When you're receiving HTTP 500 series errors, chances are the service may be in serious trouble and if you hammer it with retries, you're probably not helping to remediate the situation. Common strategies to mitigate this include exponential backoffs - you wait a little bit longer before each retry and in general different circuit breaker patterns. These should be keywords you can use in your research. You can take a look at the `DelaySeconds` parameter in the SQS `SendMessage` API ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html)) to help you with these efforts.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. I was looking at doing something similar to what is discussed here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-sqs-dead-letter-queues-to-replay-messages/ which incorporates exponential backoff and a retry counter. Any particular reason against option 1 (and using SQS `Maximum receives` as the counter)?

Comment: The implementation in that article seems fine, it includes the aspects I mentioned - exponential backoffs + keeping track of retries in the message - even though they chose the message attributes, which makes more sense now that I think of it. Option 1 would just have more complexity and Maxium receives doesn't do exponential backoffs afaik.